# Angular 2 Typescript Highcharts Highmap mouse wheel scroll

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts, mousewheel, highmaps

I'm just wondered if its not possible to subscribe to the zooming event in a highmap (Angular 2 Typescript Highcharts/Highmap) - or even to a mouse wheel scrolling event.

```
 @HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
   onScroll(e) {
     // do smth - but never reached 
    }
```

It's only called if you scroll on the divs border - but not in the map (it only zooms in/out, thats okay but i want to add smth)

Already tried to set `(scroll)="yourFunction($event)"` to the map div and a container div.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this
you may want to look @ xAxis.events.setExtremes And/Or chart.events.selection